# Calculating Football Scores

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to workout out a fantasy football games in Google sheets.

So the format is:

```
Brighton & Hove Albion  0   2   Manchester City
Manchester City 1   1   Everton
Bournemouth 1   2   Manchester City
Manchester City 5   0   Liverpool
Watford 0   6   Manchester City
```

With each field in a separate column.

The scoring system is, 2 points per goals scored, 3 points for a win and 1 point for a draw. Can you help with a Google sheet formula to work the points out for Manchester City scores?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, so I can only find a way to do this manually.

So for the first game, the total points would be 7 = 2 x 2 (Goals Scored), 3 points for win
Second game, 2 points for goal scored, 1 point for draw so total 3
Third game, total points would be 7 = 2 x 2 (Goals scored), 3 points for win

Comment: I currently have it in a Google Doc with manual scores 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_ESzC5o4_HQRds4PuxQhPVE2qxOVIMtUNs2lkxPdLw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My bad, that should be a 1 as it's a draw

Comment: My bad again, sorry that should be 6, 2 for each goal and nothing extra as they lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=if(and(A2="Manchester City",B2>C2),3+2*B2,if(and(A2<>"Manchester City",C2>B2),3+2*C2,if(B2=C2,1+2*B2,if(and(A2="Manchester City",B2<C2),2*B2,if(and(A2<>"Manchester City",C2<B2),2*C2)))))
```